# form submit on changing value of input field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a single attribute and i want to submit the form on changing the value of the only attribute but somehow the change event is not firing up.
here is my code

```js
function triggerClick(){
 $('#user_profilepic').trigger('click');
};

$('#user_profilepic').change(function(){
 $('form#updateAvatar').submit();
});
```

```css
#updateAvatar{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<form id="updateAvatar" class="simple_form edit_user" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/edit/updateAvatar" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group file optional user_profilepic">
  <label class="file optional control-label" for="user_profilepic">Profilepic</label>
  <input id="user_profilepic" class="file optional" type="file" name="user[profilepic]">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Update User" name="commit">
</form>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Share your html, Fiddle would be better.

Comment: i have pasted my html code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhans/z7ozq654/1/)
Make sure your html is loaded before running the jQuery code by `$(document).ready()`